# Powershell - inject content into json file

Tags: json, powershell, aws-cloudformation

I have to inject some data into json file. I am using powershell code, presented below. This is only extract from my script. Variable `$MwTagsSelected` is an array of pscustom objects, it looks like below.
`$MwTagsSelected` has three properties: `TagIndex`,`TagName`,`TagValue`. I am passing that object through below presented `foreach` loop, in a result I am getting object array `$FilteredObjectArray`. Both object arrays are presented below. I want to inject `$FilteredObjectArray` into json file, using code `$jsoncontent.Resources.MaintenanceWindowTarget.Properties.Targets = $FilteredObjectArray`

$MwTagsSelected:

[image]

$FilteredObjectArray

[image]

My powershell code:

```
# get JSON file content
$filename = "inputfile.json"
$content = Get-Content -Path .\$filename
$jsoncontent = $content | ConvertFrom-Json
# JSON file input preparation
$Keys = ($MwTagsSelected | Select-Object -Property TagName -unique).TagName
$FilteredObjectArray = @()
$NotAllowedSelections = @()
$Value = @()

foreach ($Key in $Keys) {
        $Value += $MwTagsSelected | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.TagName -eq $Key}
        $FilteredObject = [pscustomobject][ordered] @{
            Key = "tag:$Key"
            Values = $Value.TagValue
        }

    if ($Value.Count -gt 5) {
        $NotAllowedSelections += $Key
    }
    $FilteredObjectArray += $FilteredObject
    $Value = @()
}

$jsoncontent.Resources.MaintenanceWindowTarget.Properties.Targets = $FilteredObjectArray

$jsoncontent | 
ConvertTo-Json -Depth 15 | 
Set-Content .\test.json
```

As an output of that script I am getting json file, but the json structure is not as expected, below extract from my output test.json file.

```
"Targets": [
          {
            "Key": "tag:win",
            "Values": [
              "01",
              "02"
            ]
          },
          {
            "Key": "tag:ein",
            "Values": "03"
          }
        ],
```

Output test.json file should looks like below:

```
"Targets": [
          {
            "Key": "tag:win",
            "Values": [
              "01",
              "02"
            ]
          },
          {
            "Key": "tag:ein",
            "Values": [
              "03"
            ]
          }
        ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to ensure the values is an array you can surround it with `@()`

```
    $FilteredObject = [pscustomobject][ordered] @{
        Key = "tag:$Key"
        Values = @($Value.TagValue)
    }
```

See these simplified examples

**Sample data**

```
$ht = @{
    Tag="win"
    TagValue=1,2
},
@{
    Tag="ein"
    TagValue=3
}
```

**Without `@()`**

```
$ht.GetEnumerator() | % {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Key = $_.tag
        Values = $_.tagvalue
    }
}  | ConvertTo-Json

[
    {
        "Key":  "win",
        "Values":  [
                       1,
                       2
                   ]
    },
    {
        "Key":  "ein",
        "Values":  3
    }
]
```

**With `@()`**

```
$ht.GetEnumerator() | % {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Key = $_.tag
        Values = @($_.tagvalue)
    }
}  | ConvertTo-Json

[
    {
        "Key":  "win",
        "Values":  [
                       1,
                       2
                   ]
    },
    {
        "Key":  "ein",
        "Values":  [
                       3
                   ]
    }
]
```

Also as an aside, you do not need `[Ordered]` with `[PSCustomObject]` - it will retain the order by default.

Comment: Hi, yes, it works, I've just tested the solution, thank You!!